# Watch Uploaded Videos Not Youtube Embeds

Tags: html, video, tags

I am trying to view my locally uploaded videos but it is not showing fullscreen options! I don't want Youtube Embeds but rather my own videos. Also I don't want to use the HTML 5  tags. I want an iframe for some reason. Thanks in advance

```
<div><iframe src="uploads/<?php echo $video['upload']; ?>"></div>
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Why don't you want to use HTML5 `<video>` tag? if you don't like the default player you can easily extend/skin it.

Answer (score 0):

In most modern browsers you can add the `allowfullscreen` attribute to the iFrame:

```
<div><iframe src="uploads/<?php echo $video['upload']; ?>" allowfullscreen></div>
```

though your milage may vary depending on how the browser defaults to handling the raw video.

My recommendation would be to not use an `<iframe>` but the HTML5 `<video>` element unless you have a compelling reason

```
<div><video controls src="uploads/<?php echo $video['upload']; ?>" preload="auto"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is actually helpful. Thank you!